# Integration with Euler number and sin2x

Tags: integration

I found this example in a textbook:
$$\int e^{\cos^2 x}\sin2x dx$$

There are also results, but I am not even close to that...

Comment: Use the substitution $u=\cos^2(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Try using $\sin 2x= 2\sin x \cos x$ and $d(\cos x)=-\sin x \,dx$, then integrate by parts.

Answer (score 0):

$$u= \cos^2(x)$$ Then
$$I=-\int e^{u}du=-e^{u}+C=-e^{\cos^2(x)}+C$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $\sin(2x) = 2 \sin(x) \cos(x)$ and 
\begin{align}
\partial_{x} e^{\cos^{2}(x)} &= e^{\cos^{2}(x)} \cdot \partial_{x} ( \cos^{2}(x) ) \\
&= - 2 \sin(x) \cos(x) \cdot e^{\cos^{2}(x)} = - \sin(2x) e^{\cos^{2}(x)}
\end{align}
which leads to
\begin{align}
\int \sin(2x) \ e^{\cos^{2}(x)} \ dx = - e^{\cos^{2}(x)}.
\end{align}

Comment: Mighty peculiar notation for a simple derivative, isn't it?  Why not $\frac{d}{dx}$ instead of the odd $\partial_x$?

Comment: in single variable calculus: $\partial_{x} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} = \frac{d}{dx}$.

Comment: And ∂_x is less typing than d/dx.

Comment: @Leucippus: I understand the notation, of course, but it seems inappropriate for this question. I doubt the OP knows it given the nature of the question.

Comment: @Urgje: Let's see... "\frac d{dx}" has 11 characters, "\partial_x" has 10 characters. Quite a savings, that. ;)

Comment: It is since I use scientific Word.

Answer (score 0):

**Even Better Hint:** Try putting $u=\cos^2 x$ and consider $\int e^u\,du$

Answer (score 0):

Use the identity that 
$$\frac{d}{dx}e^{f(x)}=\frac{df(x)}{dx}e^{f(x)}\Rightarrow \int \frac{df(x)}{dx}e^{f(x)}dx$$

Setting $f(x)=\cos^2x$, can you find $\frac{df(x)}{dx}$ using the chain rule? How does it compare with the integral you have to evaluate?

Also, note that $\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$ .